# WCF return type : JsonResult

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I want a service to return the data in following JSON format (not a string):

```
{{name:"ABC"},{Id:"ABC123"}}
```

I am trying to return a `JsonResult` from a WCF function. I created an `IList<Dictionary>` to store the data fetched from the database, then I converted it to a `JsonResult` using the `Json()` function of Controller class. I was expecting to receive JSON data from this service when tested using Fiddler, instead I receive a 504 result saying:

> "[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response
>   for this request. Server returned 0 bytes."

What could be the reason?

Comment: Can you add your WCF method that returns the JSON response?

Comment: I would first consider serializing something other than an IList to the result.  If this data is ever consumed by .NET or requires deserialization, what type should it convert the JSON back into (since a type cannot be inferred from an IList)?  Consider an array of Dictionary instead.  Also, more code would sure help.

Comment: Are you sure you mean WCF? Controllers and JsonResult are a WebApi/MCV thing, not WCF...

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using mvc's JsonResult in wcf, is it a requirement? You can return a Json.NET's JObject object instead of the JsonResult, or dynamic object like this:

```
public dynamic GetData()
{
     dynamic objReturn = new ExpandoObject();
     objReturn.Id = "ABC123";
     objReturn.name = "ABC";
     JavaScriptSerializer objSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     return objSerializer.Serialize(objReturn);
}
```

Comment: Do you suspect the use of the `JsonResult` type to be causing the issue the OP presented?  Seems like this may not be an answer.

Comment: Yes, I want the output to be in JSON format. Whereas, the values are retrieved from DB which are dynamic so I cannot use [DataMember] or [DataContract] (since the objects are dynamically created).

Answer (score 0):

Setup a trace log which you can open in traceviewer to find out more about the error. Alter the config file as shown in the following MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Not sure if this helps, but when I return an object or a list I create an object of the type I want to return, making sure Ive included the DataContract and DataMember attributes to serialize it. For example:

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{      
    [DataMember(Name="email")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }


    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Create a service interface, returning a list of the user objects

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/users", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<User> GetUsers();
```

Implement the interface, and when you return you list it will get transparently serialised to JSON

```
public List<User> GetUsers()
{
    List<User> userList = new List<User>();   
    //Create your user list here

    return userList;
}
```

Comment: I cannot use  DataContract and DataMember because the objects are created dynamically from the database and that is the reason why I am using Dictionary. But returning dictionary gives the result in {{key="name":value="ABC"}} format which I want to convert to {{name:"ABC"}} format.